# Timer given for Enemy spawning is not pausing when the game is in paused mode

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a simple shooting game, in which the enemies will spawn at each clock tick, for which I have used a simple TimerEvent.. And now  I am having a issue, when I press Pause button the game pauses properly, but the timer of enemy spawning is not getting paused. The enemy continues to get spawn. My pause code contains only `stage.framerate = 0`. So please help me for the above issue.. Thanks in advance..
My main code is -

```
package
{
    import........
    ..............

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        //var declearations...

        //Timer Events declearation....



private function timeStart():void
        {
            Timer1 = new Timer(1000,180);
            Timer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,TimerStart);
            Timer1.start();

        }

private function TimerStart(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            createEnemy(enemy1,Enemy1,enemies1);
        }

private function createEnemy(enemy:MovieClip,enemyClass:Class, enemyArray:Array)
        {
            enemy = new enemyClass(bg_mc);
            enemyArray.push(enemy);
            bg_mc.addChild(enemy);
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not pause, it does not depend on `stage.frameRate`. In order to align your framerate and enemies appearance, use a listener to `Event.ENTER_FRAME` which will both count frames until next enemy, move everything frame by frame (you most likely have this part made), spawn new enemies and control paused state - you can do a simple `if (weArePaused) return;` at the beginning of the listener to make the pause without altering `stage.frameRate`.